# How to solve error CS0103: the name 'minutes' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am currently doing a tree-house course in which you create a fitness console app that records your input exercise time , tallies it and gives you feedback depending on your  and have received no help in the treehouse community , so if anyone could help me find a solution to the following it would be great help , im not sure if it has something to do with where the variable is placed , if it is in-between the braces in which in is called. Im not too sure im really new to this

```
using System;
namespace Treehouse.fitnessFrog
{
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
      int runningTotal = 0;
      bool keepGoing = true;

        while(keepGoing) {
           // Prompt user for minutes exercised 
            Console.Write("Enter how many minutes you exercised or type quit to exit ");
            string entry = Console.ReadLine();

            if(entry == "quit")
            {
              keepGoing = false;

            }else{

              try
              { 
                int minutes = int.Parse(entry);
                if(minutes <= 0)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Acceptable");
                continue;
              }
              else if(minutes <= 10)// Number 1 
              {
                Console.WriteLine("Better than nothing, am I right ?");
              }
              else if(minutes <= 30) // Number 2
              {
                Console.WriteLine("You are still quite lazy");
              }
              else if(minutes <= 60) // Number 3 
              {
                Console.WriteLine("Your doing all right i guess. But work on you're spelling!");
              }
              else 
              {
                Console.WriteLine("Cool story bro");
              }
              }
              catch(FormatException)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("That is not valid");
                  continue;
              }                   
            // Add minutes exercised to total 
            runningTotal = runningTotal + minutes;

            // Display total minutes exercised to the screen 
            Console.WriteLine("You've entered "+ runningTotal + " minutes");

            // Repeat until user quits  
        }


      }
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye mate"); 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Move the declaration of minutes to the same level of the declaration of runningTotal, also having a good indentation of your code could help to spot these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare variable `minutes` outside `try` block:

```
int minutes = 0; // create variable here
try
{ 
    minutes = int.Parse(entry); // here only use this variable
    if(minutes <= 0)
    {
        // your code
    }
    //else if statements
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you , unfortunately doing that created another error but i then noticed to move the whole int minutes = int.Parse line above the try block, and it works no more errors 
Thanks heaps

Comment: If you move the whole line outside try block, you won't catch exception if the argument of int.Parse() will be wrong - if entry variable will be i.e. "abc"

Comment: So what would i do ? Sorry just cause im new to this

Comment: What error do you get when you change your code as in answer?